# AWS Lambda multiple triggers issue - Redshift Unload to S3 - ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I am currently working on Redshift and I am executing an Unload function using a partition by parameter on an id column to an S3 bucket.

The Unload function with the partition generates multiple files in the S3 folder.
I added a trigger to the S3 folder so I can process each partition.

The behaviour I am expecting is a Lambda function invoked for each partition, so 4 partitions will trigger 4 lambdas and each event would contain only the name of a single partition.

This seems to be working as expected if the Lambda runs successfully but if there happens to be an error I see an unexpected behaviour from the Lambda.
Basically it looks like the same Lambda was triggered by all the partitions at the same time.

I can see in fact inside the logs multiple START RequestIds, and if I print the event I can see an event for each partition that was created in the same log, while as mentioned I would be expecting to be only 1 event which is the partition.

I see that the ObjectCreated from the event is ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload.

Do you know how can I prevent such behaviour and ensure that only 1 partition is triggering only 1 Lambda?

Thanks